# What are the disadvantages with using Ecofont in an Enterprise?

Tags: fonts

Based on this question: [Which font would save more printer's ink/toner?](https://superuser.com/questions/340869/which-font-would-save-more-printers-ink-toner)

Are there any drawbacks using for example [Ecofont](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ecofont) in an Enterprise? I'm thinking about:

1. Are there any copyrights on the Font?
2. Are there any better, more economic Fonts like Ecofont?
3. Is it easy to install it? How can I do it on WinXP/Win7/Ubuntu/Debian/Fedora/etc.?
4. Does it really save 10-20% ink?
5. Does the printed text has the exact same lifetime? (vs. a normal font) doesn't Ecofont wear out faster compared to a normal font?
6. Are there any websites that has a lists of companies that changed the "default font" to something like Ecofont?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/340869/which-font-would-save-more-printers-ink-toner

Comment: so afaik if we plan to use the "ecofont_vera_sans_regular.ttf" in our company as default font, we do not need to pay any license fee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any copyrights on the Font?

Just like any professionally produced font, you can't just use it without getting or buying a license. Ecofont is a bit different:

- There is Ecofont software, a whole printing software. You won't have to typeset your documents in Ecofont, you just have to print them using the software.

  Actually, in most jurisdictions, fonts are treated like software, so you buy licenses to use them. Depending on the size of the company, the number of workstations where it will be installed, the organization type, you will receive a [quote by Ecofont](http://www.ecofont.com/en/general/contact/quotation-form.html).

  You can also use a [demo version](http://www.ecofont.com/en/help/ecofont/faq/0002.html). It includes an option to [buy the license](http://www.ecofont.com/en/help/ecofont/faq/0022.html).
- You *can* use the [normal "Ecofont Vera Sans" typeface](http://www.ecofont.com/en/products/green/font/download-the-ink-saving-font.html) which doesn't require any software and should come for free.

> Are there any better, more economic Fonts like Ecofont?

See the [linked question](https://superuser.com/questions/340869/which-font-would-save-more-printers-ink-toner).

> Is it easy to install it? How can I do it on WinXP/Win7/Ubuntu/Debian/Fedora/etc.?

The fonts themselves, just like you would install any other font that comes as OpenType or TrueType. In Windows, just right-click and install. In Ubuntu and similar, [there's a Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts). There are of course [resources for Fedora](http://blog.urfix.com/install-fonts-fedora-easily/) too.

Since Ecofont actually is a printing software package that offers more than just the font, they have a [FAQ](http://www.ecofont.com/en/help/ecofont/faq.html) if you encounter any issues. This software runs on Windows, OS X and Linux.

> Does it really save 10-20% ink?

If you trust their information, yes. But you'll have to read reviews.

> Does the printed text has the exact same lifetime? (vs. a normal font) doesn't Ecofont wear out faster compared to a normal font?

Normally yes, but it rather depends on how good your printers are (inkjet vs. laser), what kind of paper you use (heavy vs. normal), but not on the font. Given that the font uses less ink, it might expire faster if your printer produces bad quality prints.

> Are there any websites that has a lists of companies that changed the "default font" to something like Ecofont?

On Ecofont's website itself:

[image]

Comment: so afaik if we plan to use the "ecofont_vera_sans_regular.ttf" in our company as default font, we do not need to pay any license fee?

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but there is no license agreement you see when downloading "just" the font. (Btw. any reason for accepting-unaccepting?)

Answer (score 0):

1. For one thing licencing- It IS copyrighted and they sell a software that lets you do it with your  - they would need a version of nearly every font and may not work with all fonts. They have a freely available varient based off bitstream vera sans, which is under a  [very permissive licence](http://www-old.gnome.org/fonts/)
2. Century gothic is one font thats often mentioned
3. If its a standard truetype or opentype font its portable across OSes
4. no idea
5. No reason it shouldn't, but that would vary on so many different things, ink type/toner paper, storage conditions etc
6. If anyone, ecofont or someone else flogging a similar product

Comment: so afaik if we plan to use the "ecofont_vera_sans_regular.ttf" in our company as default font, we do not need to pay any license fee?

Comment: that particular one, no - as i stated, explicitly in my answer, as its a derivative of a font under an open source licence, and they have chosen not to charge for it (they *could* as long as they met the terms of the licence the font its based off us under)

Answer (score 0):

> Does the printed text has the exact same lifetime? (vs. a normal font) doesn't Ecofont wear out faster compared to a normal font?

I would expect this to depend largely on the **quality** of the ink and paper used, with only a marginal effect due to the **quantity** of ink deposited on the page.

The higher the quality of these the longer the printing will "last".

Comment: so afaik if we plan to use the "ecofont_vera_sans_regular.ttf" in our company as default font, we do not need to pay any license fee?

Comment: @LanceBaynes- the other answers indicate that you do have to pay a license fee.

Comment: ecofont_vera_sans_regular.ttf ? where?

Answer (score 0):

1. they have their own font so I assume it will have some copyrights (you need licenses also for the software, as a font is also a program)
2. if you just look for an alternative to save on printing you could have a look at [Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info/overview/eco), which is widely used in enterprises. Ofcourse this is not a font.